# database passes Date=40683 as this type of int

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am being passed a date in this format DepartDate=40683, in vb.net
however i cant figure out how to convert the integer into a regular date

Comment: Do you know what the corresponding date is for that number?

Comment: Is that supposed to represent 4/6/1983?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an SQL Server it's likely the internal storage format of the date that you are getting, which is the number of days since 1900-01-01. You can use the `DateTime.AddDays` method to convert it. Example:

```
Dim n as Integer = 40683
Dim DepartDate As DateTime = New DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddDays(n)
```

Comment: You are right, and for some reason who ever did this one used 12/30/1899

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, you're under SQL SERVER:

> SQL Server uses 8 bytes to store the
>   datetime data type. The first 4 bytes
>   make up an integer value that
>   represents the number of days since
>   January 1, 1900.
>   The second 4 bytes are an integer
>   value that represents the number of
>   milliseconds since midnight.

So assigning this value(`40683`) to a `datetime` variable, you'll get a `2011-05-22 00:00:00.000` as date value.